# Polymorphism and equals in Java

Tags: java, polymorphism, overloading, equals

Class Paren contains only an int.

```
public class Paren 
{
    private int _val=0;

    public Paren()
    {
        _val=10;
    }

    public Paren(int val)
    {
        _val=val;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "val=" + _val ;
    }
}
```

Class Chil extends class Paren, also contains a String and overloads the equals method 3 times: 
1. takes an Object parameter
2. takes a Paren parameter
3. takes a Chil parameter

```
public class Chil extends Paren 
{
    private String _st;

    public Chil()
    {
        _st="child";
    }

    public Chil(String st, int val)
    {
        super(val);
        _st=st;
    }

    public String getSt()
    {
        return _st;
    }

    public boolean equals (Object ob) 
    {
        if ((ob != null) && (ob instanceof Chil))
        {
            if (_st.equals(((Chil)ob)._st) &&
            (getVal() == ((Chil)ob).getVal()))
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean equals (Paren ob) // shita 2
    {
        if ((ob != null) && (ob instanceof Chil))
        {
            if (_st.equals(((Chil)ob)._st) &&
            (getVal() == ((Chil)ob).getVal()))
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean equals (Chil ob) 
    {
        if (ob != null)
        {
            if (_st.equals(((Chil)ob)._st) &&
            (getVal() == ((Chil)ob).getVal()))
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I instantiate objects thusly:

```
Paren A = new Chil();
Chil B = new Chil();
```

A polymorphically holds a Chil object. When I call

```
A.equals(B)
```

the call jumps to 1. equals() that takes an Object parameter

If A is a Chil and B is a Chil, why doesn't it go to the equals() that takes a Chil parameter?

Comment: It can't call the overloaded `equals` methods in `Chil`, because the variable is of type `Paren`, and the overloaded methods are not declared for `Paren`. It resolves to `equals(Object)` (which `Paren` inherits from `Object`), and then at runtime the overridden implementation of `equals(Object)` in `Chil` is called.

Comment: you declared all of the overloaded equals methods in Chill but you call it from Paren reference so your A reference can only see equals(Object obj) from new Chil();
if you call B.equals(A); you will get equals(Paren obj);

Comment: Method signature is picked at *compilation* time. Polymoprhism only guarantees that code which will be executed for that method will be searched at runtime based on *actual object type held in reference variable*. For `Paren A` when you use `A.equals(B)` compiler cant assume what will be actual type held in `A` so he allows only method signatures available for `Paren` class which is `equals(Object)` inherited from Object class. Later you overwritten this method in `Chil` class so via polymoprhism you invoked that overwritten code.

Answer (score 0):

When the compiler sees `A.equals(B)` it searches for methods named `equals` defined in `Paren` class (the compile time type of A) or the ancestors of `Paren` class. It finds `equals(Object)` in the `Object` class. It doesn't find the `equals` methods defined in `Chil` class, so it can't choose the methods having the `equals (Paren ob)` or `equals (Chil ob)` signatures.

This is method overloading, determined at compile time.

At runtime, the JVM sees that the runtime type of `A` is `Chil` and that `Chil` overrides `equals (Object ob)`, so it executes `Chil`'s `equals (Object ob)`.

Comment: When I see such questions I start looking for duplicates ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`A` acts like `Paren` which doesn't have a `equals (Chil ob)`. What it has is `equals(Object o)` from `Object` class. Hence, at compile time, compiler binds this call to `equals(Object o)` and hence tis invoked.